# what is the best low maintenance finish for a hardwood floor

Tags: wood, floor, finish

Home made mesquite flooring.  What is the best floor finish?  Low traffic but subject to spills...this is for the man cave.  Installing diy mesquite floor tiles, 4 - 6" width, random lengths.  Aprox 1/4 inch mesquite glued to 3/4 inch construction grade plywood....avoiding voids.

Comment: I think some kind of a drying oil, or even a good hard polyurethane would make sense here.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to beat Polyurethane for durability.  I have had good success with both water based and solvent based versions. Get the stuff made for floors, probably two coats would do you.  You don't want it too smooth or you'll die when it's wet.

That is, unless you have small children, then I would suggest poured concrete ;)

Comment: I like Polyurethane for easy clean up, the kids like it with socks they can slide a long way, Ok I did this as a kid also.

Comment: Ok thanks...been thinking polyurethane but wasn't sure.  Probably will go with the water based.  Rarely will kids be an issue...this is the man cave!  At least as long as my wife says its ok.

Comment: Besides...can't disagree with a Beal!